# C# Select Random Row from Datagridview

Tags: c#, select, random, datagridview

I have a C# application where I load song titles from the database to datagridview, Now I already have next and previous buttons

Obviously the next button selects the proceeding row while the previous button selects the preceeding row

I want to create another button that will randomly select any row from the datagridview and prevent selecting the same row twice. This code I found in a thread and altered a bit doesn't seem to work

```
private Random rnd = new Random();
private int lastSelectedIndex = -1;
void RandomRecord() { 
    int noRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count[0];
    int index = rnd.Next(noRows);
    while(index == lastSelectedIndex && noRows > 1) { 
        index = rnd.Next(noRows);
    } 
    lastSelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is a bit vague. What does it do? What does the value of lastSelectedIndex end up as? `dataGridView1.Rows.Count[0]` looks a bit suspect BTW. Don't think Count is an array?

Comment: You code is not selecting any row in the DGV.  You get a random number and then do nothing with the number.

Comment: Nothing ever happens when I click it.

Comment: that'll be because of what jdweng said. You generate a value but don't use it to actually do anything in the datagridview. It's just a variable all by itself.

Comment: I see

So I generate a random number, how do I then assign it to a row number for it to be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling RandomRecord method, you must set the selected row. For example, use this:

```
dataGridView.Rows[lastSelectedIndex].Selected = true;
```

Or, you can use this row after setting lastSelectedIndex in the RandomRecord method.